# MySQL queries stacking up and crashing

Tags: mysql, centos

We have an application with around 300k active users. We have a dedicated database server which has the following configurations. The problem we are facing is that randomly we get alot of load on our server and it gets hanged and we have to restart mysql service in order to continue. We have monyog installed on the database server to monitor which queries are taking much time but whenever the crash occurs it doesnt seems to show any unusual activity just that the queries start to stack up alot and even the normal ones start taking time more than 2 minutes. We have optimized our database in every way possible in our knowledge like adding index to the tables optimizing queries minimizing number of queries.

Below are our configurations

```
server.cnf
[mysqld]
    innodb_force_recovery = 0
    port            = 3306
    socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
    datadir=/var/lib/mysql
    skip-external-locking
    performance_schema=ON
    query_cache_limit=1M
    query_cache_size=16M
    query_cache_type=1
    max_user_connections=32000
    max_connections=32000
    interactive_timeout=180
    wait_timeout=180
    connect_timeout=10
    thread_cache_size=200
    max_connect_errors=999999
    max_allowed_packet=512M
    table_open_cache=90000
    innodb_file_per_table=1
    myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
    tmp_table_size=32M
    max_heap_table_size=32M
    default-storage-engine = innodb

[mysqldump]
    quick
    max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

limits.conf

```
*                hard    nofile          199680
*                soft    nofile          16364
```

Application Architechture

language: Php5

Mysql Version

```
innodb_version  5.6.36-82.2
protocol_version    10
slave_type_conversions  
version 10.1.28-MariaDB
version_comment MariaDB Server
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os  Linux
version_malloc_library  system jemalloc
version_ssl_library OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
wsrep_patch_version wsrep_25.20
```

its MariaDB

OS: CentOS

cat /proc/meminfo

```
MemTotal:       131729252 kB
    MemFree:        74397484 kB
    MemAvailable:   97158916 kB
    Buffers:            4884 kB
    Cached:         23181052 kB
    SwapCached:            0 kB
    Active:         53580240 kB
    Inactive:        1336380 kB
    Active(anon):   32095004 kB
    Inactive(anon):   279912 kB
    Active(file):   21485236 kB
    Inactive(file):  1056468 kB
    Unevictable:           0 kB
    Mlocked:               0 kB
    SwapTotal:       1048572 kB
    SwapFree:        1048572 kB
    Dirty:                76 kB
    Writeback:             0 kB
    AnonPages:      31730916 kB
    Mapped:           139488 kB
    Shmem:            644244 kB
    Slab:            1190592 kB
    SReclaimable:     897028 kB
    SUnreclaim:       293564 kB
    KernelStack:       15536 kB
    PageTables:        84744 kB
    NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
    Bounce:                0 kB
    WritebackTmp:          0 kB
    CommitLimit:    66913196 kB
    Committed_AS:   89544808 kB
    VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
    VmallocUsed:      550556 kB
    VmallocChunk:   34258290684 kB
    HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
    AnonHugePages:  18024448 kB
    HugePages_Total:       0
    HugePages_Free:        0
    HugePages_Rsvd:        0
    HugePages_Surp:        0
    Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
    DirectMap4k:      281112 kB
    DirectMap2M:    14270464 kB
    DirectMap1G:    121634816 kB
```

the query to `show status like '%abort%';`

```
Aborted_clients 3098
Aborted_connects    141795
wsrep_local_bf_aborts   0
```

Below is my mysql_error.log but its only showing up the things after i restarted the mysql service

```
2017-10-26 23:36:56 140677528500480 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-10-26 23:36:56 140677528500480 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-10-26 23:36:56 140677528500480 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@db.dbsuer.com' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-10-26 23:36:56 140677528500480 [Warning] 'user' entry '@db.dbsuer.com' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-10-26 23:36:56 140677528500480 [Warning] 'user' entry 'jon@monitoring.got-servers.net' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-10-26 23:36:56 140677528500480 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@db.dbsuer.com' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-10-26 23:36:56 140677528058624 [Warning] Failed to load slave replication state from table mysql.gtid_slave_pos: 1146: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist
2017-10-26 23:36:56 140677528500480 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.28-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
2017-10-26 23:36:56 7ff205748b00 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2017-10-27  2:12:44 140588045855488 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown
2017-10-27  2:13:04 140588045855488 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 26950259  user: 'dbuser'

2017-10-27  2:13:04 140588045855488 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 26950237  user: 'dbuser'

2017-10-27  2:13:04 140588045855488 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 26908783  user: 'dbuser'

2017-10-27  2:13:04 140588045855488 [ERROR] mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
2017-10-27  2:13:04 140588045855488 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 6885924  user: 'root'

2017-10-27  2:13:04 140588045855488 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 2139  user: 'root'

2017-10-27  2:13:14 140588619900672 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2017-10-27  2:13:14 140588045855488 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2017-10-27 02:14:54 7fafc7e6b900 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2017-10-27  2:14:54 140392949790976 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-10-27  2:14:54 140392949790976 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-10-27  2:14:54 140392949790976 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-10-27  2:14:54 140392949790976 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2

SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;

'Aborted_clients', '108'
'Aborted_connects', '5565'
'Access_denied_errors', '0'
'Acl_column_grants', '0'
'Acl_database_grants', '3'
'Acl_function_grants', '0'
'Acl_procedure_grants', '0'
'Acl_proxy_users', '1'
'Acl_role_grants', '0'
'Acl_roles', '0'
'Acl_table_grants', '0'
'Acl_users', '21'
'Aria_pagecache_blocks_not_flushed', '0'
'Aria_pagecache_blocks_unused', '15706'
'Aria_pagecache_blocks_used', '28'
'Aria_pagecache_read_requests', '553397'
'Aria_pagecache_reads', '6463'
'Aria_pagecache_write_requests', '71168'
'Aria_pagecache_writes', '0'
'Aria_transaction_log_syncs', '0'
'Binlog_bytes_written', '0'
'Binlog_cache_disk_use', '0'
'Binlog_cache_use', '0'
'Binlog_commits', '0'
'Binlog_group_commit_trigger_count', '0'
'Binlog_group_commit_trigger_lock_wait', '0'
'Binlog_group_commit_trigger_timeout', '0'
'Binlog_group_commits', '0'
'Binlog_snapshot_file', ''
'Binlog_snapshot_position', '0'
'Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use', '0'
'Binlog_stmt_cache_use', '0'
'Busy_time', '0.000000'
'Bytes_received', '779126531'
'Bytes_sent', '7848821242'
'Com_admin_commands', '193376'
'Com_alter_db', '0'
'Com_alter_db_upgrade', '0'
'Com_alter_event', '0'
'Com_alter_function', '0'
'Com_alter_procedure', '0'
'Com_alter_server', '0'
'Com_alter_table', '0'
'Com_alter_tablespace', '0'
'Com_analyze', '0'
'Com_assign_to_keycache', '0'
'Com_begin', '0'
'Com_binlog', '0'
'Com_call_procedure', '25'
'Com_change_db', '2186510'
'Com_change_master', '0'
'Com_check', '0'
'Com_checksum', '0'
'Com_commit', '0'
'Com_compound_sql', '0'
'Com_create_db', '0'
'Com_create_event', '0'
'Com_create_function', '0'
'Com_create_index', '0'
'Com_create_procedure', '0'
'Com_create_role', '0'
'Com_create_server', '0'
'Com_create_table', '0'
'Com_create_temporary_table', '2'
'Com_create_trigger', '0'
'Com_create_udf', '0'
'Com_create_user', '0'
'Com_create_view', '0'
'Com_dealloc_sql', '0'
'Com_delete', '164'
'Com_delete_multi', '0'
'Com_do', '0'
'Com_drop_db', '0'
'Com_drop_event', '0'
'Com_drop_function', '0'
'Com_drop_index', '0'
'Com_drop_procedure', '0'
'Com_drop_role', '0'
'Com_drop_server', '0'
'Com_drop_table', '0'
'Com_drop_temporary_table', '4'
'Com_drop_trigger', '0'
'Com_drop_user', '0'
'Com_drop_view', '0'
'Com_empty_query', '0'
'Com_execute_sql', '0'
'Com_flush', '0'
'Com_get_diagnostics', '0'
'Com_grant', '0'
'Com_grant_role', '0'
'Com_ha_close', '0'
'Com_ha_open', '0'
'Com_ha_read', '0'
'Com_help', '0'
'Com_insert', '7530'
'Com_insert_select', '5'
'Com_install_plugin', '0'
'Com_kill', '1'
'Com_load', '0'
'Com_lock_tables', '0'
'Com_optimize', '0'
'Com_preload_keys', '0'
'Com_prepare_sql', '0'
'Com_purge', '0'
'Com_purge_before_date', '0'
'Com_release_savepoint', '0'
'Com_rename_table', '0'
'Com_rename_user', '0'
'Com_repair', '0'
'Com_replace', '0'
'Com_replace_select', '23'
'Com_reset', '0'
'Com_resignal', '0'
'Com_revoke', '0'
'Com_revoke_all', '0'
'Com_revoke_role', '0'
'Com_rollback', '0'
'Com_rollback_to_savepoint', '0'
'Com_savepoint', '0'
'Com_select', '2769447'
'Com_set_option', '1685912'
'Com_show_authors', '0'
'Com_show_binlog_events', '0'
'Com_show_binlogs', '0'
'Com_show_charsets', '0'
'Com_show_collations', '19'
'Com_show_contributors', '0'
'Com_show_create_db', '0'
'Com_show_create_event', '0'
'Com_show_create_func', '0'
'Com_show_create_proc', '0'
'Com_show_create_table', '1'
'Com_show_create_trigger', '0'
'Com_show_databases', '19'
'Com_show_engine_logs', '0'
'Com_show_engine_mutex', '0'
'Com_show_engine_status', '19'
'Com_show_errors', '0'
'Com_show_events', '0'
'Com_show_explain', '0'
'Com_show_fields', '2'
'Com_show_function_status', '0'
'Com_show_generic', '0'
'Com_show_grants', '0'
'Com_show_keys', '2'
'Com_show_master_status', '20'
'Com_show_open_tables', '1912'
'Com_show_plugins', '0'
'Com_show_privileges', '0'
'Com_show_procedure_status', '0'
'Com_show_processlist', '329'
'Com_show_profile', '0'
'Com_show_profiles', '0'
'Com_show_relaylog_events', '0'
'Com_show_slave_hosts', '0'
'Com_show_slave_status', '2'
'Com_show_status', '429'
'Com_show_storage_engines', '0'
'Com_show_table_status', '0'
'Com_show_tables', '5'
'Com_show_triggers', '0'
'Com_show_variables', '50'
'Com_show_warnings', '5'
'Com_shutdown', '0'
'Com_signal', '0'
'Com_start_all_slaves', '0'
'Com_start_slave', '0'
'Com_stmt_close', '1703'
'Com_stmt_execute', '2110'
'Com_stmt_fetch', '0'
'Com_stmt_prepare', '2110'
'Com_stmt_reprepare', '0'
'Com_stmt_reset', '0'
'Com_stmt_send_long_data', '0'
'Com_stop_all_slaves', '0'
'Com_stop_slave', '0'
'Com_truncate', '0'
'Com_uninstall_plugin', '0'
'Com_unlock_tables', '6263'
'Com_update', '23649'
'Com_update_multi', '0'
'Com_xa_commit', '0'
'Com_xa_end', '0'
'Com_xa_prepare', '0'
'Com_xa_recover', '0'
'Com_xa_rollback', '0'
'Com_xa_start', '0'
'Compression', 'OFF'
'Connection_errors_accept', '0'
'Connection_errors_internal', '0'
'Connection_errors_max_connections', '0'
'Connection_errors_peer_address', '0'
'Connection_errors_select', '0'
'Connection_errors_tcpwrap', '0'
'Connections', '2102550'
'Cpu_time', '0.000000'
'Created_tmp_disk_tables', '6776'
'Created_tmp_files', '6'
'Created_tmp_tables', '24053'
'Delayed_errors', '0'
'Delayed_insert_threads', '0'
'Delayed_writes', '0'
'Delete_scan', '26'
'Empty_queries', '971314'
'Executed_events', '0'
'Executed_triggers', '0'
'Feature_delay_key_write', '0'
'Feature_dynamic_columns', '0'
'Feature_fulltext', '0'
'Feature_gis', '0'
'Feature_locale', '0'
'Feature_subquery', '4177'
'Feature_timezone', '0'
'Feature_trigger', '0'
'Feature_xml', '0'
'Flush_commands', '1'
'Handler_commit', '1561805'
'Handler_delete', '132151'
'Handler_discover', '3'
'Handler_external_lock', '0'
'Handler_icp_attempts', '258439030'
'Handler_icp_match', '254844311'
'Handler_mrr_init', '0'
'Handler_mrr_key_refills', '0'
'Handler_mrr_rowid_refills', '0'
'Handler_prepare', '0'
'Handler_read_first', '280'
'Handler_read_key', '35395424'
'Handler_read_last', '16'
'Handler_read_next', '9410864982'
'Handler_read_prev', '81650'
'Handler_read_retry', '0'
'Handler_read_rnd', '28068980'
'Handler_read_rnd_deleted', '0'
'Handler_read_rnd_next', '59836719'
'Handler_rollback', '2'
'Handler_savepoint', '0'
'Handler_savepoint_rollback', '0'
'Handler_tmp_update', '694783'
'Handler_tmp_write', '5656429'
'Handler_update', '79769'
'Handler_write', '109219'
'Innodb_available_undo_logs', '128'
'Innodb_background_log_sync', '1115'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data', '6600916992'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty', '267239424'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status', 'Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status', 'Loading buffer pool(s) not yet started'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data', '402888'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty', '16311'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed', '1'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free', '4154055'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_lru_flushed', '0'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_made_not_young', '0'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_made_young', '320'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc', '30513'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_old', '149969'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total', '4587456'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead', '63121'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted', '0'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd', '0'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests', '2157996469'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_reads', '337111'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free', '0'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests', '4816856'
'Innodb_checkpoint_age', '128276390'
'Innodb_checkpoint_max_age', '13914982934'
'Innodb_data_fsyncs', '1213'
'Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs', '0'
'Innodb_data_pending_reads', '0'
'Innodb_data_pending_writes', '0'
'Innodb_data_read', '6583128576'
'Innodb_data_reads', '402049'
'Innodb_data_writes', '32494'
'Innodb_data_written', '144898048'
'Innodb_dblwr_pages_written', '1'
'Innodb_dblwr_writes', '1'
'Innodb_deadlocks', '1'
'Innodb_defragment_compression_failures', '0'
'Innodb_defragment_count', '0'
'Innodb_defragment_failures', '0'
'Innodb_encryption_key_rotation_list_length', '0'
'Innodb_encryption_n_merge_blocks_decrypted', '0'
'Innodb_encryption_n_merge_blocks_encrypted', '0'
'Innodb_encryption_n_rowlog_blocks_decrypted', '0'
'Innodb_encryption_n_rowlog_blocks_encrypted', '0'
'Innodb_encryption_num_key_requests', '0'
'Innodb_encryption_rotation_estimated_iops', '0'
'Innodb_encryption_rotation_pages_flushed', '0'
'Innodb_encryption_rotation_pages_modified', '0'
'Innodb_encryption_rotation_pages_read_from_cache', '0'
'Innodb_encryption_rotation_pages_read_from_disk', '0'
'Innodb_have_atomic_builtins', 'ON'
'Innodb_have_bzip2', 'OFF'
'Innodb_have_lz4', 'OFF'
'Innodb_have_lzma', 'ON'
'Innodb_have_lzo', 'OFF'
'Innodb_have_snappy', 'OFF'
'Innodb_history_list_length', '130'
'Innodb_ibuf_discarded_delete_marks', '0'
'Innodb_ibuf_discarded_deletes', '0'
'Innodb_ibuf_discarded_inserts', '0'
'Innodb_ibuf_free_list', '64803'
'Innodb_ibuf_merged_delete_marks', '428176'
'Innodb_ibuf_merged_deletes', '123181'
'Innodb_ibuf_merged_inserts', '1178'
'Innodb_ibuf_merges', '4385'
'Innodb_ibuf_segment_size', '64805'
'Innodb_ibuf_size', '1'
'Innodb_log_waits', '0'
'Innodb_log_write_requests', '339325'
'Innodb_log_writes', '32398'
'Innodb_lsn_current', '614688828236'
'Innodb_lsn_flushed', '614688813752'
'Innodb_lsn_last_checkpoint', '614560551846'
'Innodb_master_thread_active_loops', '1115'
'Innodb_master_thread_idle_loops', '0'
'Innodb_max_trx_id', '8368506565'
'Innodb_mem_adaptive_hash', '1689900176'
'Innodb_mem_dictionary', '299754541'
'Innodb_mem_total', '78721843200'
'Innodb_mutex_os_waits', '6963'
'Innodb_mutex_spin_rounds', '1490291'
'Innodb_mutex_spin_waits', '1332026'
'Innodb_num_index_pages_written', '0'
'Innodb_num_non_index_pages_written', '32402'
'Innodb_num_page_compressed_trim_op', '0'
'Innodb_num_page_compressed_trim_op_saved', '0'
'Innodb_num_pages_decrypted', '0'
'Innodb_num_pages_encrypted', '0'
'Innodb_num_pages_page_compressed', '0'
'Innodb_num_pages_page_compression_error', '0'
'Innodb_num_pages_page_decompressed', '0'
'Innodb_oldest_view_low_limit_trx_id', '8368503775'
'Innodb_onlineddl_pct_progress', '0'
'Innodb_onlineddl_rowlog_pct_used', '0'
'Innodb_onlineddl_rowlog_rows', '0'
'Innodb_os_log_fsyncs', '1122'
'Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs', '0'
'Innodb_os_log_pending_writes', '0'
'Innodb_os_log_written', '144864256'
'Innodb_page_compression_saved', '0'
'Innodb_page_compression_trim_sect1024', '0'
'Innodb_page_compression_trim_sect16384', '0'
'Innodb_page_compression_trim_sect2048', '0'
'Innodb_page_compression_trim_sect32768', '0'
'Innodb_page_compression_trim_sect4096', '0'
'Innodb_page_compression_trim_sect512', '0'
'Innodb_page_compression_trim_sect8192', '0'
'Innodb_page_size', '16384'
'Innodb_pages0_read', '237'
'Innodb_pages_created', '1079'
'Innodb_pages_read', '401809'
'Innodb_pages_written', '1'
'Innodb_purge_trx_id', '8368504055'
'Innodb_purge_undo_no', '0'
'Innodb_read_views_memory', '2600'
'Innodb_row_lock_current_waits', '0'
'Innodb_row_lock_time', '950387'
'Innodb_row_lock_time_avg', '4658'
'Innodb_row_lock_time_max', '41902'
'Innodb_row_lock_waits', '204'
'Innodb_rows_deleted', '132151'
'Innodb_rows_inserted', '56069'
'Innodb_rows_read', '9463155799'
'Innodb_rows_updated', '79769'
'Innodb_s_lock_os_waits', '44208'
'Innodb_s_lock_spin_rounds', '3808201'
'Innodb_s_lock_spin_waits', '738548'
'Innodb_scrub_background_page_reorganizations', '0'
'Innodb_scrub_background_page_split_failures_missing_index', '0'
'Innodb_scrub_background_page_split_failures_out_of_filespace', '0'
'Innodb_scrub_background_page_split_failures_underflow', '0'
'Innodb_scrub_background_page_split_failures_unknown', '0'
'Innodb_scrub_background_page_splits', '0'
'Innodb_secondary_index_triggered_cluster_reads', '306821502'
'Innodb_secondary_index_triggered_cluster_reads_avoided', '0'
'Innodb_system_rows_deleted', '0'
'Innodb_system_rows_inserted', '0'
'Innodb_system_rows_read', '0'
'Innodb_system_rows_updated', '0'
'Innodb_truncated_status_writes', '0'
'Innodb_x_lock_os_waits', '23001'
'Innodb_x_lock_spin_rounds', '7705254'
'Innodb_x_lock_spin_waits', '94569'
'Key_blocks_not_flushed', '0'
'Key_blocks_unused', '214330'
'Key_blocks_used', '4'
'Key_blocks_warm', '0'
'Key_read_requests', '84'
'Key_reads', '4'
'Key_write_requests', '0'
'Key_writes', '0'
'Last_query_cost', '0.000000'
'Master_gtid_wait_count', '0'
'Master_gtid_wait_time', '0'
'Master_gtid_wait_timeouts', '0'
'Max_statement_time_exceeded', '0'
'Max_used_connections', '300'
'Memory_used', '445027144'
'Not_flushed_delayed_rows', '0'
'Open_files', '12'
'Open_streams', '0'
'Open_table_definitions', '263'
'Open_tables', '400'
'Opened_files', '27460'
'Opened_plugin_libraries', '0'
'Opened_table_definitions', '267'
'Opened_tables', '525'
'Opened_views', '0'
'Performance_schema_accounts_lost', '0'
'Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost', '0'
'Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost', '0'
'Performance_schema_digest_lost', '0'
'Performance_schema_file_classes_lost', '0'
'Performance_schema_file_handles_lost', '0'
'Performance_schema_file_instances_lost', '0'
'Performance_schema_hosts_lost', '0'
'Performance_schema_locker_lost', '0'
'Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost', '0'
'Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost', '0'
'Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost', '0'
'Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost', '0'
'Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost', '0'
'Performance_schema_socket_classes_lost', '0'
'Performance_schema_socket_instances_lost', '0'
'Performance_schema_stage_classes_lost', '0'
'Performance_schema_statement_classes_lost', '0'
'Performance_schema_table_handles_lost', '0'
'Performance_schema_table_instances_lost', '0'
'Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost', '0'
'Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost', '0'
'Performance_schema_users_lost', '0'
'Prepared_stmt_count', '0'
'Qcache_free_blocks', '1918'
'Qcache_free_memory', '5902288'
'Qcache_hits', '1209722'
'Qcache_inserts', '1347881'
'Qcache_lowmem_prunes', '943761'
'Qcache_not_cached', '211725'
'Qcache_queries_in_cache', '5647'
'Qcache_total_blocks', '13458'
'Queries', '8782988'
'Questions', '8778832'
'Rows_read', '3758678584'
'Rows_sent', '9669002'
'Rows_tmp_read', '6550750'
'Rpl_status', 'AUTH_MASTER'
'Select_full_join', '9637'
'Select_full_range_join', '3'
'Select_range', '188883'
'Select_range_check', '0'
'Select_scan', '6116'
'Slave_connections', '0'
'Slave_heartbeat_period', '0.000'
'Slave_open_temp_tables', '0'
'Slave_received_heartbeats', '0'
'Slave_retried_transactions', '0'
'Slave_running', 'OFF'
'Slave_skipped_errors', '0'
'Slaves_connected', '0'
'Slaves_running', '0'
'Slow_launch_threads', '0'
'Slow_queries', '24'
'Sort_merge_passes', '0'
'Sort_priority_queue_sorts', '16808'
'Sort_range', '17758'
'Sort_rows', '376035'
'Sort_scan', '10237'
'Ssl_accept_renegotiates', '0'
'Ssl_accepts', '0'
'Ssl_callback_cache_hits', '0'
'Ssl_cipher', ''
'Ssl_cipher_list', ''
'Ssl_client_connects', '0'
'Ssl_connect_renegotiates', '0'
'Ssl_ctx_verify_depth', '0'
'Ssl_ctx_verify_mode', '0'
'Ssl_default_timeout', '0'
'Ssl_finished_accepts', '0'
'Ssl_finished_connects', '0'
'Ssl_server_not_after', ''
'Ssl_server_not_before', ''
'Ssl_session_cache_hits', '0'
'Ssl_session_cache_misses', '0'
'Ssl_session_cache_mode', 'NONE'
'Ssl_session_cache_overflows', '0'
'Ssl_session_cache_size', '0'
'Ssl_session_cache_timeouts', '0'
'Ssl_sessions_reused', '0'
'Ssl_used_session_cache_entries', '0'
'Ssl_verify_depth', '0'
'Ssl_verify_mode', '0'
'Ssl_version', ''
'Subquery_cache_hit', '0'
'Subquery_cache_miss', '5000'
'Syncs', '2'
'Table_locks_immediate', '1581465'
'Table_locks_waited', '0'
'Tc_log_max_pages_used', '0'
'Tc_log_page_size', '4096'
'Tc_log_page_waits', '0'
'Threadpool_idle_threads', '0'
'Threadpool_threads', '0'
'Threads_cached', '118'
'Threads_connected', '118'
'Threads_created', '309'
'Threads_running', '6'
'Update_scan', '5'
'Uptime', '1124'
'Uptime_since_flush_status', '1124'
'wsrep_cluster_conf_id', '18446744073709551615'
'wsrep_cluster_size', '0'
'wsrep_cluster_state_uuid', ''
'wsrep_cluster_status', 'Disconnected'
'wsrep_connected', 'OFF'
'wsrep_local_bf_aborts', '0'
'wsrep_local_index', '18446744073709551615'
'wsrep_provider_name', ''
'wsrep_provider_vendor', ''
'wsrep_provider_version', ''
'wsrep_ready', 'OFF'
'wsrep_thread_count', '0'
```

We have 5 databases with almost 200 million rows altogether. To my knowledge we can do some stuff but that would come under optimizing and reducing the load. Apart from any bad queries what can be done to prevent the crashes? 
We used to get alof of errors like

```
too many open files
too many connections 
cannot connect right now
```

But by researching and configuring right parameters we have overcome those but the crashing has been there for a while now and its become more frequent. 
There is nothing much is the `mysql_error.log` as well
Any help would be great!

Comment: What does the `/var/log/mysql/error.log` display? Could you [add](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/189481/edit) that information to your question? Then you could have a look at the `show status like '%abort%'` in your mysql and trigger it to see which of the counters is increasing. This can give you a hint of what is happening: See [B.5.2.11 Communication Errors and Aborted Connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/communication-errors.html)

Comment: Why are you allowing any hacker 999999 login attempts to break in to your server with your max_connect_errors tolerance?  How much RAM does your server have?  Please post your php.ini and text results of the following 
A. SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;  B. SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; C. SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;  for possible advice.

Comment: added the show global status result, RAM is listed 131729252 i.e. 128GB. What about max_connect_errors ? what should that be?

Comment: Anyone's tolerance for hackers should be limited to no more than 10 attempts.  IMHO. 
 You have 128GB RAM. I see your GLOBAL STATUS under error.log content.  Today, can not see ini, B or C. Please post your php.ini and text results of the following B. SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; C. SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; for possible advice.

Comment: My error earlier, this number indicates you have 128MB RAM.  Please post whatever you are looking at as text.

Comment: Considering the error about `innodb_table_stats`, I wonder if you upgraded without running mysql_upgrade?

Comment: `MemTotal:       131729252 kB` == 128GB.

Comment: `'Uptime', '1124'` -- Please replace the `STATUS` after the server has been running at least a day; not much info can be gleaned from only 1124 seconds.  Also provide `SHOW VARIABLES`.  Can't judge one without the other.

Comment: Some of the stats imply the existence of some inefficient queries (long scans, disk-based tmp tables, etc).  Suggest you find one of the worst queries and start another Question to discuss improving it.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: its not about one queries, recently what I have seen in the error logs is this error 2017-10-28 23:39:35 139595687332608 [ERROR] mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
2017-10-28 23:39:35 139595687332608 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 236287974  user: 'dbuser'

Comment: There are many things that needs to be consider, is Memory, CPU, I/O of at hardware is stable? do you have any monitoring tool implemented which can help you regarding this? have you spread I/O level by placing logs & data files to different locations? what sort of hard drives you are using? what about big tables? are you doing archiving/purging? are you using Master slave replication? if so have distributed read/writes? are you using semi sync, that would also cause delays? .. Please do think in those lines to get optimal performance

Comment: Seeing as your `aborted_connects` status is pretty high, you might have a rogue application connecting to your database, but which is losing its connection again. If you run `show status like '%abort%?'` over a short period of time, how fast does that counter increase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following suggestions need your research before implementing ONLY one item per day. Some may be applied dynamically. Suggested cfg/ini values follow, could be modify, add or remove.

```
innodb_print_all_deadlocks=1 # from OFF for daily review in error log
log_warnings=2 # for additional info on connect failures for research
these first two are DYNAMIC and could/should be done NOW, add to cfg/ini
review your PREPARE, EXECUTE, CLOSE code.  STATUS indicates ~ 400 not closed
status threads_connected of 118 = resources not released, when client done
thread_cache_size=100 # from 200 to prevent OOM per V8
max_connections=1000 # from 32000, until stabilized, 300 max_used since start
table_open_cache=10000 # from 90000, 525 were opened since start
open_files_limit=30000 # from default for ratio of toc * 3
```

ensure ulimit will support requested volumes

Consider installing MySQLTuner.com and posting report in Question.

When GLOBAL VARIABLES become available, there will be additional opportunities.
When appropriate, keep us informed, accept if it helps, please.

---- 2017 11 02  additional observation, with aborted_connections of 5555 and threads_connected, does your application have a convenient 'logoff' available?  If not, please consider adding to allow releasing of resources and use of CLOSE functions.

---- 2017 11 05  how is it possible to have 
'Connections', '2102550'
in uptime of 1124  seconds?  About ~1800 per second per posted status.  With a master/slave this may be reasonable.

Comment: These tips are a good start.  More can be had from `VARIABLES` and `GLOBAL STATUS` _after_ running for a day.  (MySQLTuner is usually not very useful.)

Comment: @rickjames  MySQLTuner is quite helpful with version, storage engine statistics (table space used, and number of tables per engine), RAM, connections, threads, tables/files and other significant details in the Metrics groups, some with limits and counts that are very helpful.  Recommendations must be carefully scrutinized.  Sometime alarms are raised unnecessarily, i.e. 'Beware that open_files_limit (1024) variable should be greater than table_open_cache (400)'  It is, so why not just add text of 'OK at this time.'   to clarify that they know we are OK.

Comment: It almost always recommends `OPTIMIZE TABLE`, which is rarely useful.

Comment: @RickJames i cant post the whole thing here due to characters limit, would you mind giving me your email id or something? I need a mysql expert on this. Thanks

Comment: You can reach me at mysql at rjweb dot org .

Comment: My profile includes contact by web link that works.

Comment: @rickjames  I do not see the requested SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES or updated SHOW GLOBAL STATUS for more than 1124 seconds, we tried.

Comment: @WilsonHauck - Uptime=1124 means that mysqld was restarted 1124 seconds ago.   Wait a while before doing `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`.

Comment: @MuneebZulfiqar Please consider posting to pastebin.com the following, A. current my.cnf  B. SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; C. SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; D. SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; to allow current analysis of your HOST.  And let us know if you are making any progress, please.

Comment: @MuneebZulfiqar  please consider posting text results of 
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%savepoint%' so we can analyze savepoint count vs rollback_to_savepoint relationship, and release count.

Comment: @MuneebZulfiqar  Thank You for accepting my answer.  I suspect you are no longer crashing.  Please consider posting current results of:  
current complete my.cnf/ini and php.ini (if used)
Text results of: 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
C) complete current text of error log
D) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
E:) ulimit -a 
for a look at what is going on with your server at this time, please & Thank You.

Comment: actually the results are the same, its just a software named r1soft was running and executing flush tables which was causing all of this

Comment: @MuneebZulfiqar  Are you still crashing?  If you could post the items requested Feb 20, 2018  I would be happy to analyze current situation to see if we can improve response time with GLOBAL VARIABLE changes.  See stackoverflow.com Question 49075547 for my summary of progress with 2 sets of GLOBAL VARIABLE changes.